# Linking with TensorFlow on Arm: GLIBC_2.32, GLIBC_2.33, GLIBC_2.34 - which one?

Tags: c, tensorflow, gcc, glibc

I've built an Arm TensorFlow shared library `libtensorflowlite_c.so` on my Linux machine using the [Linux->Arm crossbuild toolchain](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/downloads).

Then I switched to Arm platform and tried to build an app linked with `libtensorflowlite_c.so`. However, the link step gives me several GLIBC link errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `fstat@GLIBC_2.33'
/usr/bin/ld: libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `__libc_single_threaded@GLIBC_2.32'
/usr/bin/ld: libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `pthread_join@GLIBC_2.34'
```

I understand that my Arm system has outdated GLIBC, older than the one from the TensorFlow lib was built with, however: there are several GLIBC versions mentioned in the error output: GLIBC_2.33, GLIBC_2.32, GLIBC_2.34. How can that be? I would expect only one GLIBC version required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no point in versioning each symbol in each glibc release, it would make *all* glibc symbols unavailable and you would have to stick to exactly one glibc version.

The symbol has a `@GLIBC_version` which is the version the symbol was *last changed*. That way you can use newer glibc, and if the symbol does not change, you can use old code on it.

When the symbol changes in a non-backward-compatible way, only then the version of the symbol is changed.

You can browse https://abi-laboratory.pro/?view=timeline&l=glibc .